# How to make 9 patch of this image properly?

Tags: android, imagebutton, nine-patch

I have this image for imagebutton, and i need to create patch 9 of it.

[image]

How should i make 9 patch, so the text and flag will be strecthed and squeezed correctly? I tried a few things and had no luck.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: ... So set up the parameters so that the center patch contains the text and flag? You already have documentation for the details of how to handle that, it seems, so at this point it sounds more like an artistic question than a programming one...

Comment: do you want to stretch the text and flag, or have it centered and stretch the other stuff?

Comment: Stretch the other stuff and keep the text and flag sharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the original assets for the button, it would make the most sense to separate out the grey button from the yellow text/flag. Creating a 9patch from the button itself will be pretty easy and assign that to the ImageButton background property. Leave the yellow with a transparent background centered as the ImageButton source.